# Do global secondary indexes in DynamoDB need to be unique?

Tags: java, database, amazon-dynamodb

Say I have an `order` table which stores orders made by users. It has the following schema:

`id (string, unique primary key)`

`userId (string, id of the user who made the user`

I'd like to add a global secondary index on the `userId` column, but it will be non-unique, i.e a single user may make multiple orders, which means there might be multiple orders with the same `userId`.

From reading the docs, I can't quite tell if this scenario would be ok, or if I need to add a range key to make the primary key be unique.

I'd prefer not to have to add a range key, so I can simply use the userId to get all the orders made by a particular user.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this scenario would be ok, global secondary index can be non unique. the only disadvantage (that i can think about) is that if you have a 'mega' user, with multiple orders (on write), it can accuse throughput capacity errors..

a good reference is here:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GuidelinesForTables.html

Comment: I could add a range key on the date value, but it seems like then its no longer possible to query just by the user id, it -always- requires passing in a date as well. May be what I need is a LSI on the date?

Comment: where is 'date' in your scheme?

Comment: Not mentioned here, but its a number column which has milliseconds of the date.