# Why do non-unique GSIs in DynamoDB cause latency and throughput errors?

Tags: amazon-web-services, indexing, amazon-dynamodb

My engineering team is considering implementing a non-unique GSI in DynamoDB. One of our colleagues warned us that this could overload the keys, causing latency issues, and Eyal Ch's answer on [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37118040/do-global-secondary-indexes-in-dynamodb-need-to-be-unique) mentions that "mega users" can cause throughput capacity errors when keys are not unique.

What causes these latency issues and capacity errors?

Comment: Think of a GSI like a table. It will be sharded across partitions based on the partition key of the GSI index. If the partition key attribute has low cardinality then you may get hot partitions unless you use adaptive capacity. Related [here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/how-amazon-dynamodb-adaptive-capacity-accommodates-uneven-data-access-patterns-or-why-what-you-know-about-dynamodb-might-be-outdated/) and [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/bp-partition-key-design.html#bp-partition-key-partitions-adaptive).

Answer (score 1):

DynamoDB indexes are separate tables that are projections from the base table. They are kept up to date by DynamoDB. If the primary key in the index is not unique enough, it can surpass the 1000 writes and 3000 reads per second a partition can support. The index might scale the partitions out, but that takes time. Meanwhile, the index is throttled and puts back pressure on the base table, essentially saying, "You're giving me too much data too quickly for me to process, so slow down!" And DynamoDB will slow down the base table if the index cannot keep up.

Therefore, it is essential for the primary key of an index to be unique enough not to cause throttling just like it is on a base table.

Comment: I am almost certain our use case is "unique enough," by that standard. It is just not actually unique. To clarify - does a "hot partition" include the entire primary key in the GSI, or only the partition key? The partitions are maybe not unique enough; the combination of partition and sort key should be.